# AddType in htaccess causes page to download

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have read about 10 questions like this, but there seems to be no answer to this simple question.

What could cause .htm files to be downloading instead of executed as php?

I am using the following code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php htm
```

I have tried many combinations but no success.

What else can I try?

All I need is .htm and .html files to execute php.

Comment: use `curl -v` or `wget -S` to check `Content-type` response header of your scripts.

Comment: Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php

Comment: So forgot what I said below, we know `application/x-httpd-php` is correct.

Comment: you have php as module or cgi-script? try http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `AddHandler` also, change `htm` to `.htm` and add `.html`

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

http://www.suffix.be/blog/addhandler-addtype-directives

Comment: What do you see? Is php installed correctly? If you put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in a `.php` file does execute?

Comment: I get this on my html pages: <!--?php and ?--> for some reason the php gets commented out.

Comment: Are you using `localhost` or shared hosting or...? Sometimes just `x-httpd-php` instead of `application/x-httpd-php` works...

Comment: i am using a testserver. I tried all possible combinations including this one

Comment: Are you putting it in .htaccess or apache.httpd.conf?

Comment: Another option is to use `<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>` in apache.httpd.conf

Comment: One more thing... Make sure .htaccess allow override is enables `AllowOverride All` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: It still fails, thx for helping I will now speak to the hosting company, maybe they can help

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but then i figured the version of php i'm using is php5.  I changed the handler to the following and it worked!

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and couldn't find the answer here. Did find it on this cpanel forum though:
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/php-script-is-not-working-in-html-file.595195/

Their advice was to use this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .htm .html .shtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

I was using PHP together with JSON though. After this PHP did work, but JSON didn't. Solved it by removing the AddType and sticking with the AddHandler

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .htm .html .shtml
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sharing my own experience with this super frustrating issue. My host got taken over by another hosting provider and they changed technologies. One of the changes allowed me to edit my own PHP version at will, but absolutely none of them (from the lowest 5.4 to the highest 7.2) worked properly. I was using a global .htaccess across all my domains (placed in the root) and had my AddType-s and AddHangler-s **at the beginning of the file**. Little that I knew - when I had been changing PHP versions, the little bugger wrote the correct string defining the proper name of my PHP version **at the very end of that .htaccess file**. When I defined the types at the beginning of the file, I was using the wrong handle and that skipped the bottom declaration altogether, Apache didn't recognize the technology and decided to spew out a direct download.

So *watch for custom PHP handle definitions on your hosting providers*.

What worked for me in the end was:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml .htm .html
</IfModule>
```

Note the "___lsphp" appended at the end of the standard "x-httpd-ea-php72" handle...

God, that ate me up so much...

Comment: Similar experience here. I had to add `AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php73___lsphp .html .htm`. I'm not sure if there's an easy way to work out the name. My hosting provider helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

In Apache and nginx ONLY work `.htaccess` file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
    SetHandler php-script
</FilesMatch>
```

I've also removed `AddHandler` and `AddType` from Apache conf (I used plesk).

Comment: Thank you Serghej, this question is 7 years old, but I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your .htaccess file (Solved)

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .php4 .php5 .html .htm .phtml .shtml
```

Comment: AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .php4 .php5 .html .htm .phtml .shtml

Answer (score 1):

Try:
application/x-httpd-ea-php5 or
application/x-httpd-ea-php56 for PHP 5.6
I had to change to this after upgrading to EasyApache 4

Doug
Smartlab Software

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .htm .html
```

Or

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .html .htm
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in .htaccess file

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .phtml