# Parse html file as php causing error

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, parsing

I need to parse html file as php. For this I just added below code in `.htaccess` file.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5-3 .php .html
```

But when I open my site downloading some files automatically. I don't know what is the issue. Somebody please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure .htaccess allow override is enables - AllowOverride All
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride
And this will fix your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024272/addtype-in-htaccess-causes-page-to-download

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

[Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)

As @Marc-François said

> Create a .htaccess file at the root of your website and add this line:
>
> > AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
>
> If your are running PHP as CGI (probably not the case), you should write instead:
>
> > AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

And of course

`AllowOverride All`

Comment: Yes .This works for me in local server.AddType application/x-httpd-php .sys.Thanks Janahka and Janne.

Comment: My htaccess file is not in root.This is my structure. www.domain.com/sys/.htaccess. In server it doesn't work.