# htaccess - AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I require the following in .htaccess so my php scripts run fine on my joomla site:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html
```

However, I have now found that html files are downloading instead of opening; what can I add to the .htaccess file to ensure it does not interfere with the above condition and html pages can be viewed instead of downloaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AddType in htaccess causes page to download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024272/addtype-in-htaccess-causes-page-to-download)

Comment: Solution on that page doesnt work