# PHP downloads instead of executes in apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, lamp

There are a lot of solutions for this but they never describe how to do it.
Like how to do this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

I don't know what people mean by this and if it works or not.
Is this a valid solution or does anyone have other solutions?

Comment: That behavior is prevented for security/copyright reasons. One does not want others downloading their PHP code over HTTP in a browser.

Comment: I feel the question is unclear and as to how you're trying to access a `.php` file. Are you using `http://localhost` or as `file:///`? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/18422140/1415724 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/17024272/1415724 to start with.

Comment: Is PHP installed on the server? `sudo apt-get install php5` on Debian, Ubuntu, etc.

Comment: As for the question, that line goes into the Apache config-file, usually httpd.conf. Seriosuly, though, this is like 101 LAMP-setup, and there are hundreds, if not thousands of setup-guides out there.

Comment: I have a lamp server but I don't know where to add the line and how